# SQL - Apply same ROW_NUMBER to non-matching rows

Tags: sql, row-number

I am using this query to calculate number of business days for certain date range:

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT [Date] AS WorkingDay,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS RN
 FROM DimDate
 WHERE IsHolidayUSA = 0
 AND IsWeekday = 1
)
SELECT
 DateStarted,
 DateCompleted,
 c2.RN - c1.RN AS CycleTime
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN cte c1
 ON t.DateStarted=c1.WorkingDay
INNER JOIN cte c2
 ON t.DateCompleted=c2.WorkingDay
```

This works fine if  DateStartedand and DateCompleted are both business days. If either one of them is null then result is also null:

So the idea is to apply following business day row_number to weekend/holiday date. For example:

```
Date        RN
2015-02-23  1 -- Mon
2015-02-24  2 -- Tue
2015-02-25  3 -- Wed
2015-02-26  4 -- Thu
2015-02-27  5 -- Fri
2015-02-28  6 -- Sat (applied row number of next business day) 
2015-03-01  6 -- Sun (applied row number of next business day)
2015-03-02  6 -- Mon
2015-03-03  7 -- Tue
2015-03-04  8 -- Wed
2015-03-05  9 -- Thu
```

EDIT:

Extracted ROW_NUMBER query and pointed to part which needs to be handled:

```
select Date as WorkingDay,

RN = 
    CASE WHEN IsHolidayUSA = 0 AND IsWeekday = 1
    THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC)
    ELSE 1 -- need to modify this one
    END 
from DimDate
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to get the row_number() only on the working days, but the trick is to then join all dates to this working day cte and also look up the next working day for the non-working days. (confusing)...

```
with dn as (

    select 
        *,
        IsWorkingDay = cast(case when IsHolidayUSA = 0 AND IsWeekday = 1 then 1 else 0 end as bit)
    from DimDate
    where [Date] between '2/23/2015' and '3/5/2015'

), wd as (
    select 
        [Date],
        WorkingDayNum = row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC)
    from dn
    where IsWorkingDay = 1

), d as (

    select 
        dn.[Date], 
        [WorkingDayNum] = coalesce(wd.WorkingDayNum, n.WorkingDayNum)
    from
        dn
        left outer join wd on wd.[Date] = dn.[Date]
        outer apply (
            select top 1 wd.WorkingDayNum 
            from wd 
            where wd.[Date] > dn.[Date]
            order by wd.[Date]
        ) n
)


select * from d order by Date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LEAD()` function to pull the `RN` value from subsequent rows, and rather than exclude dates based on the holiday/weekday fields, you can just conditionally apply the `ROW_NUMBER()` to them:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT [Date] AS WorkingDay
                    , CASE WHEN IsHolidayUSA <> 0  AND IsWeekday <> 1 THEN NULL
                           ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CASE WHEN IsHolidayUSA <> 0  AND IsWeekday <> 1 THEN 1 END ORDER BY [Date])
                           END AS RN
             FROM DimDate
            )
SELECT *,RN = COALESCE(RN,LEAD(RN,1) OVER(ORDER BY WorkingDay) ,LEAD(RN,2) OVER(ORDER BY WorkingDay))
FROM  cte
ORDER BY WorkingDay
```

You could add more `LEAD()` functions to accommodate 3 or 4 day weekends if needed.

Here's a working example to demonstrate on non-existing tables:

```
;WITH cal AS (SELECT CAST('2013-03-01' AS DATE) dt
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,dt)
              FROM cal
              WHERE dt < '2013-03-31')
     ,RN AS (SELECT *,CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,dt) IN ('Saturday','Sunday') THEN NULL
                           ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,dt) IN ('Saturday','Sunday') THEN 1 END ORDER BY dt)
                           END AS RN
             FROM  cal
             )
SELECT *,RN = COALESCE(RN,LEAD(RN,1) OVER(ORDER BY dt) ,LEAD(RN,2) OVER(ORDER BY dt))
FROM  RN
ORDER BY dt
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't return any rows at all for weekends

Comment: Tried this:

`WITH CTE AS 
(   
 select Date as WorkingDay,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS RN 
 from DimDate
 where IsHolidayUSA = 0
 AND IsWeekday = 1
)

SELECT 
distinct DateStarted,
DS_RN = CASE WHEN c1.RN IS NULL
    THEN COALESCE(LEAD(c1.RN,1) OVER(ORDER BY DateStarted),LEAD(c1.RN,2) OVER(ORDER BY DateStarted)) 
    ELSE c1.RN END
FROM myTable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte c1 ON t.DateStarted=c1.WorkingDay
--INNER JOIN cte c2 ON t.DateCompleted=c2.WorkingDay
where DateStarted = '2015-01-11'
order by DateStarted
`
And now DS_RN equals to null

Answer (score 1):

You get very close to what you want with cumulative sum.  Something like:

```
select Date as WorkingDay,
       SUM(case when IsHolidayUSA = 0 and IsWeekday = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over
              (order by [date] asc) as rn
from DimDate;
```

The problem is that this gives weekends and holidays a number equal to the *previous* workday rather than the next one.  So, modify it by adding 1 in some cases:

```
select Date as WorkingDay,
       (SUM(case when IsHolidayUSA = 0 and IsWeekday = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over
              (order by [date] asc)
        (case when IsHolidayUSA = 0 and IsWeekday = 1 then 0 else 1 end)) as rn
from DimDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) instead of ROW_NUMBER().